# Is it possible to remove the slash in this matching?

Tags: regex

I want to extend my regexp for filepaths matching and I don't know how to do it even if I see the problem.

**Innput example**

*"C://species/dinosaurs/trex.json"*

**Ouput example**

["C://species/dinosaurs" "trex" "json"]

so that I have the folder path, the filename and the extension.
I also want the folder path to be optional

**My regexp**

I tried

```
"^(.*[\\\/])?(.*)\.(.*)$"
```

It outputs

```
["C://species/dinosaurs/" "trex" "json"]
```

Almost but I have the / at the end of the head

I so tried

```
"^((.*)[\\\/])?(.*)\.(.*)$"
```

I ouputs

["C://species/dinosaurs/" "C://species/dinosaurs" "trex" "json"]

Maybe better because I juste have to remove the first match whereas in the first case I have to post-process the string.

I see the problem because several / can exist in the body so that it is harder.
Is it possible to say that the end of the first matching group can be all but not /.

I tried

```
^(.*(?!\/))[\\\/]?(.*)\.(.*)$
```

Does not work. I just discovered negative assertions but the output is

```
["C://species/dinosaurs/trex" "json"]
```

Any clue ?

Comment: `/[\/:a-z]+(?=\/)|[a-z]+/gi`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mH1yR0/1

Comment: check [this](https://regex101.com/r/pT0vG0/2)..assuming there is always file extension in last

Comment: Any particular reason you are using regex for this?  Any decent programming language should be able to split a path into the directory and the file name, and then split the extension off the file name.

Comment: rock321987 solved this, thanks. For others, numbers can also exist. I don't know if it exists, probably because Clojure use Java but It's not a huge function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^(?:(.*)/)?([^/]+)\.([^.]+)$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Visualization by [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HtY4yi4ee1aPlBFl)